# Finding closest vector to point

Tags: vector, distance, point

How can i sort vectors by distance from point?
For example i have three vectors: A, B, C and the point

[Example image with point and vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFcaX.png)

And the sorted result must be something like this: (A, C, B)

Comment: Do you mean position vectors w.r.t. origin ?

Comment: I didn't described it more completly. I need to sort it by level with regard to point. On this image http://i.imgur.com/WHi9sja.png the result is (B, A) means B is first level and A is second level w.r.t point

Comment: Your Problem looks more like a distance to line segments which you call vector. But a vector only has one coordinate per dimension. You could sort vectors by length.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But how how to find a distance? Because simple distance from point to middle point of line segment doesn't fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is more of a math question, but let me explain it here anyways. Take a look at this picture:

[image: Line segment definition for distances]

Let's define a line segment by vector **A** for the start point and **a** for the vector running through that line segment which end at the arrows end. Same is valid for the other segments B and C respectively. The point **P** as coordinates as also a vector.

Now let's make linear algebra our friend, yet be programatically efficient. 
:-)

At the example of segment **a** you can do this and with the other respectively:

1. With the dot product of **a** and **AP** (vector from A to P) you get the projection **projA** on **a** where the where **P** is closest.
2. If you set **A+ (projA)*na** (na is the the normalized **a** vector) you get the closest Point in the vector **a** of **P**.
3. Let's set **dA = A+projA*na - P** and with its length you get the closest distance to compare.

Instead of saving the distances, try to store and compare squared distance of **dA**, **dB** and **dC** and compare those instead. It will save you to compute the square root which might become very expensive.

Here is some pseudocode:

```
vector3 AP = P-A;
vector3 projA = a.dot(AP);
vector3 nA = a.normalized();
dA = A + projA*na - P;

dA2 = dA.x*dA.x + dA.y*dA.y + dA.z*dA.z;

-> Compare and sort them by that value
```

Hope it helps a bit...